# The easiest way to get only capital letters from a text and print them?

Tags: python

I just want to make an input text:

```
text = input('Your text: ')
```

And after the user types the text, I want the programme to take only capital letters from it and print them.

What does ***the easiest way*** mean? - Well, try to not use
functions, lists and stuff like that. Try to make the programme as
easy as possible. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: This will be difficult to do with your constraints.

Comment: What have you tried already? We'll be happy to give you feedback, but this isn't the place to ask someone to solve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for char in text:
   if char.isupper():
      print(char)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But how can I print them on one line?

Comment: `print(char, end="")` would stop `print` from emitting newlines

Comment: print(char, end="")

Answer (score 1):

A couple of inline ways to do it:

List comprehensions:

```py
uppercase_chars = [char for char in text if char.isupper()]
```

Filter functions:

```py
uppercase_chars = filter(str.isupper,text)
```

Although these answers both return lists, we can easily collapse them to strings using `str.join` like so:

```py
''.join(uppercase_chars)
```

These are not as simple as BVB44's answer, but they're much more likely to be seen in real-world code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop to check if each character is uppercase, and add it to a new variable if it is. How this works is:
For every character in the variable `my_string`, Python checks if the character is uppercase. If it is, it adds it to the variable `output`. This keeps everything on one line.

```
my_string = input("Type some stuff ")
output = ''
for char in my_string:
    if char.isupper():
        output = output + char
print(output)
```